# Alter a string on update to put some "/" in the middle of it MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

**The Problem**: I have mongoDB that uses a csv archive that has a

*"metrictimestamp"* field, but the field is filled with a **integer** like :

`20180201025934`, I need a way to put some "/" between the numbers so I can convert

the string to date type, something like: **"2018/02/01 02:59:34"**

Comment: what is your MongoDB version ?

Comment: 4.2.5 community version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MongoDB v`4.2` or above you can run an aggregation pipeline in updates. So we can get the [$substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/)'s of given `string` & concat all of these substrings & write result to same field, try below query :

```
db.collection.update( /** Instead of .update() you can use .updateMany() */
  {},
  [
    { $addFields :{ metrictimestamp :{ $toString : '$metrictimestamp' } } },
    {
      $addFields: {
        metrictimestamp: {
          $concat: [
            { $substr: ["$metrictimestamp", 0, 4] },
            "/",
            { $substr: ["$metrictimestamp", 4, 2] },
            "/",
            { $substr: ["$metrictimestamp", 6, 2] },
            " ",
            { $substr: ["$metrictimestamp", 8, 2] },
            ":",
            { $substr: ["$metrictimestamp", 10, 2] },
            ":",
            { $substr: ["$metrictimestamp", 12, -1] },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  ],{ multi : true }
);
```